# CSS3 Transformation - neutral Background under transformed div

Tags: html, css, background-image

My question refers to the following fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbvrp/1/)

```
<body>
    <div class="transform">Content</div>
</body>

body {
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/aQLvU9B.png");
}
```

If you hover over die content div a matrix tranformation is activated. I want the background behind this transformed div white and not showing the body background.

Any idea how I can do that without nesting the transformed div into another div? I tried to play around with :before and :after but found no working solution :(

Thanks and Regards,
Hendrik

Comment: Mate, I think that is the only way it can be done. Been sitting here thinking about it and adding another div above or below is the only solution. The HTML and CSS way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put another div before the transform, call it transform-bg and give a relative position with white background (giving it the same height and width of transform div.

Comment: Read the question clearly. Hendrik specified that he need solution without nesting the transformed div into another div.

Comment: then i dont think there is a solution

Comment: I dont think that there will be an really solution, so I will mark this answer as solution.

Answer (score 1):

As Donte Trumble says, I don't think that it can be done without adding another div ... unless you cheat a little.

Here is my solution

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbvrp/2/)

and the CSS

```
.transform{
    width: 200px; height: 200px;  
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: #DDD;
    vertical-align: bottom; 
    -o-transition:.5s;
    ms-transition:.5s;
    moz-transition:.5s;
    webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition:.5s;
}

.transform:hover {
    background-color: #CACACA;  
    -moz-transform: matrix(1, 0.05, 0.01, 1, 0, 0) scale(0.95,0.95);
    -webkit-transform: matrix(1, 0.05, 0.01, 1, 0, 0) scale(0.95,0.95);
    transform: matrix(1, 0.05, 0.01, 1, 0, 0) scale(0.95,0.95);
}

.transform:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: -1;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    ms-transition:.5s;
    moz-transition:.5s;
    webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition:.5s;
}
.transform:hover:before {
    -moz-transform: matrix(1.0005, -0.05, -0.01, 1.0005, 0, 0) scale(1.05,1.05);
    -webkit-transform: matrix(1.0005, -0.05, -0.01, 1.0005, 0, 0) scale(1.05,1.05);
    transform: matrix(1.0005, -0.05, -0.01, 1.0005, 0, 0) scale(1.05,1.05);
}
.transform:after {
    content: "Content";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #DDD;
    z-index: 1;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    ms-transition:.5s;
    moz-transition:.5s;
    webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition:.5s;
}
.transform:hover:after {
    background-color: #cacaca;
}
```

I won't explain you were I cheated ..   I leave it to you to find out ..

Comment: Not sure if I can mark ur answer as the solution for my question,but thy for this little hack - unfortnatly I can't use it in productive enviroments ;)